# c++ Math Issue, Double not returning value if math is all on the same line

Tags: c++, opencv

First off thanks for all the great questions and answers on this site! This website has a been a great resource for solving so many of my problems that others have had in the past which have already been answered. However, I've currently got a problem I can't seem to find a solution for..

I'm working with OpenCV trying to make my first C++ program and I'm experiencing a weird math issue. I'm guessing it's something simple that I'm not seeing and I hope someone can explain what I'm doing wrong.

The problem is on the line below: 
**double L1_Slope = (L1P2.y-L1P1.y) / (L1P2.x-L1P1.x);**
it's returning 0 if I do the math all on the same line, but if I break it up into 3 lines, it gives me the output I need.

I've seen similar questions about this, but they all deal with integers.
L1P1,L1P2,L2P1,L2P2 are in fact all cv::Point's - which are integers... 
but since I'm declaring L1_Slope as a double, I don't see why this would be the case.

Any Idea's? I know I can break the math up and it will work, but I can't imagine not being able to do this math on a single line.

```
cv::Point calcIntersection(cv::Point L1P1, cv::Point L1P2, cv::Point L2P1, cv::Point L2P2) {
//calculates the intersection of two lines

std::cout << "\n\nL1P1.x=" << L1P1.x << "\n";
std::cout << "L1P1.y=" << L1P1.y << "\n";
std::cout << "L1P2.x=" << L1P2.x << "\n";
std::cout << "L1P2.y=" << L1P2.y << "\n\n";

double test1 = (L1P2.y - L1P1.y);
double test2 = (L1P2.x - L1P1.x);
double test3 = test1/test2;
std::cout << "test1=" << test1 << "\n";
std::cout << "test2=" << test2 << "\n";
std::cout << "test3=" << test3 << "\n\n";

double L1_Slope = (L1P2.y-L1P1.y) / (L1P2.x-L1P1.x);
std::cout << "L1_Slope=" << L1_Slope << "\n\n";

double L1_Intersect = L1P1.y - L1_Slope * L1P1.x;
double L2_Slope = (L2P2.y - L2P1.y) / (L2P2.x - L2P1.x);
std::cout << "L2_Slope=" << L2_Slope << "\n";

double L2_Intersect = L2P2.y - L2_Slope * L2P2.x;
double intersectionX = (L2_Intersect - L1_Intersect) / (L1_Slope - L2_Slope);
double intersectionY = (L1_Slope * intersectionX + L1_Intersect);
cv::Point intersection = { static_cast<int>(intersectionX), static_cast<int>(intersectionY) };
return intersection;}
```

---

Here's what's being output in the console:

```
L1P1.x=111
L1P1.y=62
L1P2.x=578
L1P2.y=345

test1=283
test2=467
test3=0.605996

L1_Slope=0
L2_Slope=0
```

Comment: Change `double L1_Slope = (L1P2.y-L1P1.y) / (L1P2.x-L1P1.x);` to `double L1_Slope = (L1P2.y-L1P1.y) / static_cast<double>(L1P2.x-L1P1.x);` and all the math will work correctly!

Comment: Sam Varshavchik below is Correct. I did another test using coordinates that were all declared as doubles and the math works in one line, then declared them as integers and it returns 0. This is still an integer math error even though the end result is declared as a double.

Comment: And do not forget the check that the denominator is not 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double L1_Slope = (L1P2.y-L1P1.y) / (L1P2.x-L1P1.x);
```

Here, the `x` and `y` coordinates are integers. The expression evaluates to:

```
(345 - 62) / (578 - 111)
```

or

```
283 / 467
```

You'll be surprised to learn that in C++, `283 / 467` is 0. This is integer division, and is carried out as integers, no fractional part. Even though the end result gets assigned to a `double`, it's too late. The division gets evaluated first. The fractional part was already truncated, so the end result is 0.

```
double test1 = (L1P2.y - L1P1.y);
double test2 = (L1P2.x - L1P1.x);
double test3 = test1/test2;
```

Here, you're storing the numerator and the denominator into `double` variables, separately, then the division divides two `double` values:

```
283.0 / 467.0
```

This is now a floating point division, whose result is .605996

Answer (score 0):

Expressions are evaluated based on their types, not the type of the variable to which their result will be assigned.

When you do the math separately and assign each result to a `double` variable, you're implicitly casting the sub-expressions to `double`. So in effect you've got something like

```
double L1_Slope = static_cast<double>(L1P2.y-L1P1.y) / static_cast<double>(L1P2.x-L1P1.x);
```

When you put it all into one expression without (implicit or explicit) casts, you're doing integer math, more like

```
int L1_Slope_int = (L1P2.y-L1P1.y) / (L1P2.x-L1P1.x);
double L1_Slope = L1_Slope_int;
```

In this case, if the x difference exceeds the y difference, rounding will mean your less-than-one fraction will turn into an integer 0.

To force the math to `double`, you need to ensure at least one operand of each operation where it matters is a `double` (the other will be implicitly upcast if necessary). You can accomplish this either by assigning the result of one or more of the subexpressions to a `double` variable, as you saw, or by explicitly casting to `double` as shown in the first snippet in this answer.

Comment: It could have been better if you would have recommended `static_cast<double>` Instead of `(double)`